# Restrict FTP account access down to several directories

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, debian-squeeze

Is there any way, to restrict access to SSH and FTP account down to only several directories.

For example on our VPS we have some paths like:

```
@project root/proj1
@project root/proj2
@project root/proj3
```

And i want that user1 could access all three, user2 only second and user3 only first and second. Moreover is there any way to show to users only directories allowed to access?

I mean, if for example there are such directorys as:

```
/var/www/project
/var/www/project2
/var/www/project3
```

And user might go only to project and project2, but not to project3. So he could access /var/www, but not /var.

P.S. We have DirectAdminand Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making symlinks to the real locations in each users' home directory, and restricting FTP access to the home directory only.

ProFTPd can do this, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Search more by using these keywords,

> FTP virtual directories, FTP virtual user

Try this one.

http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/

Try to use **VSFTP** ,it's more secure than FTP.

Comment: ..than ProFTPd, I think you meant. FTP is not a program.

Comment: :D Yap. ftp is a protocol. You should decide what to use. From VSFTP server you can create virtual users + directories.

Comment: we have proftpd, i will dig more ;)